# SSH agent forwarding not working on LSF when using BSUB

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-agent

At my institute we have a cluster that runs LSF. Via this cluster, I want to connect to other computers/servers using Agent Forwarding. This works fine when I am on the login node, however when I am working on an interactive shell from a compute node, it fails. However when I skip the queue system and directly SSH into the compute node (so **not** using the `bsub` command), the agent forwarding works fine.

I request a shell at a compute node with this command `bsub -Is -XF -q centos7 $SHELL` (here more info about [bsub](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/bsub.zz4category.description.1.html))
It seems that after using the `bsub` command, my key cannot be found:

```
ssh-add -L
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I can tell from [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_command_ref/bsub.1.html), `-XF` only provides X11 forwarding, not agent forwarding.

Comment: Thanks, i see that it is not possible then.